# how do i handle the requests asynchrous as this isnt working, it should be alerting with the response

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("name", nickname.value);
data.append("email", email.value);
data.append("user", user.value);
data.append("passw", passw.value);

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200)
        afterSignup(req.responseText);
}
req.open("GET", server, true); // true for asynchronous 
req.send(data);

function afterSignup(req) {
    res = JSON.parse(req)["res"];
    alert(res);
}
```

im trying to handle the requests asynchronised but im just not sure how to do it, this is what i have so far

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP GET request in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)

Comment: "why am i getting empty responses" — What makes you think that you are? Nothing in the code you've shared is doing anything with the response that would display it anywhere.

Comment: @Quentin i editied the question and forgot to switch the title, before i was doing it synchronised and errored as i put true in the param but now im asking how to do it asynchrous

Comment: And what does "isnt working" mean? What do you expect to happen? How does this differ from what actually happens?

Comment: @Quentin when it calls aftersignup it should json parse it and alert but doesnt alert which means it probably never gets called

Comment: "it should json parse it and alert but doesn't alert" —Why should it do that? Hint **show us** the function you are calling. Add a debug statement at the top to see if it gets called. And if it doesn't, then figure out why. You only call it when a condition is met. *log the values that condition depends on* to see what they are. Look at the console to see if there are other error messages.

Comment: Re edit: That's a start, now please response to the bits of my last comment that aren't just the first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Change async value to false to make it synchronous.

```
req.open("POST", `${server}/signup`, false);
```

Comment: im such an idiot... cant believe i spent the last hour stuck on this. thanks for the help bro it works, but what does that param actually mean or do

Comment: No, don't do that..  It's a deprecated feature, so unless the OP is using a webworker it's going to break in the future.

Comment: @Keith so what should i use instead

Comment: @RafiAsmoucha  Check out the dupe I've just posted.

Comment: @Keith i barely used stackoverflow so how do i check that

Comment: @RafiAsmoucha Use this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript

Comment: @RafiAsmoucha  If you read the comments under your question, it should say something like -> `Does this answer your question?` with a link you can click on.  If other users also flag this link your message will get marked duplicate too.

Comment: @Keith i tried to do it asynchrous but i couldnt get it to work, im very bad with javascript and this is th efirst time ive dealt with requests at all

Answer (score -1):

There are *so* many JavaScript libraries out there ... big and small ... that I'd be hard pressed to suggest that you should spend much time re-inventing this.

For example:  https://github.com/freelancephp/simpleAjax.js

```
 simpleAjax.get('ajax.html', function (data) {
     alert(data);
 });
```

Boom.  Done.  Over and out.  The author says his library is "cross-platform," "even works for IE7+" *(yuck)*, and is about 3KB minified.  So, "just grab it and go."

(There are *hundreds* of packages out there like this one ... AJAX has truly been done to death.)

Comment: thanks, im still dumb tho so what part of my code would this replace

Comment: How does this library solve the problem the OP is having?

Comment: Oh good grief. That library uses `eval` to handle JSON. Avoid it like the plague.